# How do I remove newline from the last argument in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm working on wsl bash and I have the following function defined in my `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
function clip { /mnt/c/Windows/System32/clip.exe "${@%\n}"; }
```

However this does not remove the trailing `\n` from the arugument.
How can I improve this to meet my specific needs?

Many thanks

EDIT:
With the help of [Kamil](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski)'s answer, I was able to figure out what was actually going on. turns out that the spawned subprocess (cmd.exe) is adding the carriage return which is being inserted into `clip.exe` (because I was using pipes. ex. `pwd | clip`).

I was able to get the desired result with the following:

```bsh
function clip { /mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowershell/v1.0/powershell.exe Set-Clipboard "${@:-$(cat)}"; }
```

It's a bit slow as it relies on

- powershell
- cat (external binary which should be replaced with read builtin)

But not a problem for my needs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"${@%\n}"` removes a trailing `n`. `"${@%\\n}"` would remove trailing `\n` (literal string, not a newline).

To remove a newline character you need to pass a newline character. In Bash this syntax should work:

```
"${@%$'\n'}"
```

where [`$'\n'`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) is responsible for generating an actual newline character. A literal newline will work as well:

```
"${@%
}"
```

Notes:

- The solution removes trailing newline from each argument, not only from the last (because this is how `$@` works).
- In Linux its unusual to have a trailing newline in a command line argument. I don't know WSL, I don't know your usage case; I hope you know what you want<sup>*</sup>.

---

Example:

```
$ set a $'b\n' c
$ printf '<%s>\n' "$@"
<a>
<b
>
<c>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${@%$'\n'}"
<a>
<b>
<c>
$ printf '<%s>\n' "${@%
}"
<a>
<b>
<c>
```

---

<sup>* If "removing the trailing `\n` from the argument" is not what you want, then *maybe* you call the function in a (sourced?) script and the script suffers from DOS line ending(s). Check [this question](https://superuser.com/q/39313/432690).</sup>

Comment: If Windows data is involved, do not overlook the possibility that \r is also in the mix.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Windows data will not be involved (as ```clip``` is a windows executable that copies the given argument to the clipboard). Just WSL or bash > clipboard. It will always be a '\n'.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Also, turns out that ```clip.exe``` appends a carriage return. Nothing you can do from WSL side. Thank you though!

Comment: @tinnick If you need to remove a carriage return instead of a newline, use `"${@%$'\r'}"`. If you need to remove a CR-LF pair, it's `"${@%$'\r\n'}"`